# Inscribing Plot window in the console and do not want the plot window popping up separately

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am facing couple of issues. First, I wanted all the plots in a separate window. For this, I successfully changed the settings and I got the separate window. The problem is, I got all the plots in same figures, which is bad. Second issue is, how do I inscribe window pan to the Ipconsole? I donot want a separate window. I want this window inside the console?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, you can have your plots in different figures by using `figure` this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
# Plot your first graph(s)

plt.figure()
# Plot your other graph(s)

plt.show()
```

Each time you call `figure`, a new window is created. For more information on `figure`, you can check [the doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html)

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to inscribe the plot window pan to the ipconsole ?